# A property of the imaginary circle at infinity

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space

I'm trying to understand the following property:

Given an oblique cone (second order), the imaginary circle at infinity can be represented as an imaginary circle with radius equal to the height of the cone and whose center is the orthogonal projection of the cone's vertex over the plane that contains the cone's base (in this case is a conic section). This property is used in the construction of the rectangulars axis for the cone. Could you gime me some explanations or may be a reference to read about this property? Thanks

Comment: Where did you hear about this?  A book?  A lecture?  And if the imaginary circle has a center in the plane and finite imaginary radius how is it a circle at infinity?

Comment: THE IMAGINARY CIRCLE AT INFINITY: Any sphere S cuts the plane at infinity in an imaginary circle. Consider any plane H. This cuts S in a circle. The points where this circle meets the line at infinity of H are the circular points at infinity of H. They are on the sphere S and therefore on its circle of intersection with the plane at infinity. This circle of intersection is therefore the locus of the circular points at infinity in all planes.It is called the circle at infinity (the imaginary circle at infinity) and all spheres contain it.

Comment: Book: Introduction to projective geometry by L.N.G. FILON CHAP 13: The cone and sphere, page 217

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of circles with imaginary radius, that's where I was confusing myself.